# WinHttp Async Timeout issue

Tags: c++, winhttp

I am trying to use WinHTTP C++/Windows API in order to connect to multiple Http servers. Before switching to WinHTTP, i tried using HttpClient C# 4.5 in async manner, however i did not get high throughput and the CPU was too high.

On WinHTTP, a single request should not take more than 100ms; however i noticed that when using WinHTTPSetTimeouts it has no effect even when setting timeout to 10ms, still a single request to a port on the same machine takes 15-30ms, and when connecting to a port no body listens to, the request takes up to 1000ms, therefore, i concluded that timeout is not working.

In addition, i noticed that the time taken to fire a GET request on the same machine takes 15-30ms which is too high compared to .NET which takes 2-7ms...

I also tried setting connect/recv/send timeout to 1 second, yet the receive operation timeout after 4 seconds.

Do you have a clue how to work it out with timeouts and why a single request is taking time.